# Javascript/html make the timer stop when you stop typing (after 10 seconds of your last word

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


    <h1><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
<script>
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="myInput"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    time;
}
</script>


    <script>
document.getElementById("myInput").onkeypress = function() {Start()};

function Start() {
time;}
}

function Stop(){
clearTimeout(t);
}
</script>
```

how can I make it to where after you stop typing then it takes 10 seconds for the timer to pause.
not keyup because it doesn't count the LAST phrase because it just counts down as your typing.

I'm using Dreamweaver and making a program after this but I can't get the timer to stop after you stop typing (10 countdowns)

Comment: I think you are looking for triggering the timer onkeyup event. So create an event listener that utilizes that event with your timer part of the logic inside of the event, to do the thing after 10 seconds. 

Edit: I guess it would be something like ```onkeyup = stopTimer () => { something about clearTimeout... }```
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Comment: I left an answer below, but I think you would have an easier time understanding all this if you took the time to consistently indent your code, and delete parts that are unrelated to the question at hand

Answer (score 1):

You might have some success replacing the block around your version of `myFunction` with something like

```
<script>
    timer = null
    function myFunction() {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        timer = setTimeout(Stop, 10000)
    }
</script>
```

This will replace the value of `timer` every time that `myFunction` is called, with a new 10 second countdown. So if you call `myFunction` on keyup, the timer will keep getting reset as long as the user is continuously typing

As Jacob mentioned below, it also probably makes sense to modify your input to use `keyup`

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be tied into the event from keyup?

Comment: yeah, their code above has `<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">`

Comment: From the sound of what they are looking for, they should likely change the event listener to "onkeyup" I think your logic solves the issue itself though.

Comment: would you be able to write it in with the rest of my code.. im not that great at coding but i researched some more and couldn't get it to work. it just stopped the timer the second i started it up, so its stuck at 00:1.